# ASP.NET MVC 4 get value from IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this variable here: `var value = service.Get(UserId)` this returns data from an IQueryable and has results. I am looking to grab the language from the results in the screenshot below, how would I do that? I tried `value[0].language` but that did not work :(

Any suggestions would be helpful:

[image]

I am looking to get the language value of "english"
 Please help.

I tried: `string value = service.Get(UserId).FirstOrDefault().Language;`

I am getting an error 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Here is what I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Model;
using CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Api.Services;
using CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Data.Repositories;
using CTHRC.Roti.Data.EntityFramework.Repositories;
using CTHRC.Roti.Data.EntityFramework;
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "but that did not work"?

Comment: `.Get(UserId)` returns `IEnumerable`? Interesting. Unless it's `params Int32[] userIds` that's very strange behavior.

Comment: didn't work because C# is case sensitive try value[0].Language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Cast() like below

```
 string Language= service.Get(UserId).Cast<Users>().FirstOrDefault().Language;
```

Comment: I am getting an error 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: have you got in your header using System.Linq ?

Comment: I get an error with the cast error: No overload for method 'Cast' takes 1 arguments

Comment: string Language= service.Get(UserId).Cast<Users>().FirstOrDefault().Language; sorry users in <> bracket

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56390/discussion-between-user3723240-and-sylwester).

Answer (score 2):

IQueryables are slightly different than plain arrays. In order to see the results view, you had to enumerate the IQueryable. You can actually see that in your screen shot where it says "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable". This quote is the key to this scenario. If the IEnumerable is not enumerated, then no actual data is brought from the database. There are various ways in code to enumerate the IEnumerable such as using .ToList, .Select, .Single, .First, and a few others.

I believe you will be interesting in using `.FirstOrDefault()`. The "OrDefault" part just means if the list is empty no exception is thrown. This may or may not be desirable depending on the scenario.

```
string language = service.Get(UserId).FirstOrDefault().Language;
```

in order to avoid an exception if there are no users returned, a projection could be first used.

```
string language = service.Get(UserId).Select(u => u.Language).FirstOrDefault();
```

which will produce *null* if there were no users.

Comment: While you wont get an exception on the `FirstOrDefault` call, you will get a `NullReferenceException` instead.

Comment: @Matthew - As a result of Default being `default(User)`, yes, it will still generate that exception. Perhaps another check would be required for null in that case. A projection could also be used, see the last edit.

Comment: @user3723240 - If you right click on `FirstOrDefault` can you "Resolve" by importing a namespace?

Comment: Interesting. In order to fix that, you should include the directive `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I am using System.Linq;

Comment: Then you should not see that issue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: service.Get(UserId) implement IQueryable not IEnumerable and IQueryable hasn't got method FirstOrDefault() please read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @sylwester - That is not the interface that should be implemented. See here for proper exposure to the IQueryable interface. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb351562(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Several options, in your code value is a list of items not a value.

```
string xyz = value[0].Language;
```

or

```
Just get a single item

var item = service.Get(UserId).FirstOrDefault();
string xyz = item.Language;
```

if not strongly typed
    string xyz = item["Language"];

Answer (score 0):

I concur with sywester's answer but with a little tweak. You have to check for null first or you'll introduce a null bug into your system.
So

`var a = service.Get(UserId).FirstOrDefault();
string Language = a!=null? a.Language : string.Empty;`

Comment: do you have a reference to System.Linq? Like `using System.Linq;`